# Question regarding rewriting sum of sine and cosine into a single cosine term

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Let's say that we have the following function:
$$
x(t) = A_1\cos(\omega t) + A_2\sin(\omega t)
$$

Then we can rewrite it by defining a right triangle with an angle $\delta$, which has adjacent side $A_1$, opposite side $A_2$, and hypotenuse $A = \sqrt{A_1^2 + A_2^2}$. So
$$
\delta = \arctan \frac{A_2}{A_1}.
$$

It then follows that:
$$
x(t) = A \biggl( \frac{A_1}{A}\cos(\omega t) 
+ \frac{A_2}{A}\sin(\omega t) \biggr) 
= A \bigl( \cos(\delta)\cos(\omega t) 
+ \sin(\delta)\sin(\omega t) \bigr) 
= A\cos(\omega t - \delta).
$$

---

However, let's say we now have the following function:
$$
x(t) = A_1e^{i\omega t} + A_2e^{-i \omega t} 
= (A_1+A_2)\cos(\omega t) + (A_1-A_2)\,i\sin(\omega t).
$$

It turns out that this can still be rewritten as
$$
x(t) = A\cos(\omega t - \delta).
$$

But how and why? Because we now have a complex amplitude $(A_1-A_2)i$ for the $\sin(\omega t)$ part. So using the same definition of the right triangle now doesn't make sense right?

How are $A$ and $\delta$ supposed to be defined now compared to before?

Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$y=A e^{ix} + B e^{-ix} =(A+B)\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2+(A-B)i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=$$
$$=(A+B)\cos x+(A-B)i\sin x$$

and by summation formula we have

$$y= C\cos(x - \delta)=C\cos(x )\cos( - \delta)+C\sin(x )\sin( - \delta)$$

then

- $C\cos(  \delta)=A+B$
- $-C\sin( \delta)=(A-B)i$

therefore we need that $A=\bar B$ such that $A+B$ and $(A-B)i$ are real.

Note that the same result can be obtained directly observing that $y$ is real if and only if $A e^{ix}$ and $B e^{-ix}$ are conjugate which requires $A=\bar B$.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that $x(t)$ is real is if its imaginary part is identically zero, i.e. that $A_1 - A_2 = 0$ in the expansion you give for $x(t)$. This is only possible if $A_1 = A_2$, in which case, by defining $A = 2 A_1$,
$$
x(t) = A_1 e^{i\omega t} + A_1 e^{-i\omega t} = A \cosh(i\omega t) = A \cos(\omega t).
$$

Comment: We are not necessarily claiming that x(t) is real, just that it can be rewritten that way. I am wondering how you would define A and delta then. In the theory of solving second order differential equation, every textbook I see claims that you can still rewrite a sum of two complex exponentials as a single cosine with a phase shift, which is confusing.

Comment: @Stallmp Your formula for x(t) implies it is real.

Comment: With retrospect it makes sense that x(t) is real. But then it doesn't make sense for the author to claim that that form can be rewritten like that, if we impose the condition that A1=A2 which essentially removes the phase shift as well right?

I added a new image as reference.